# Dosbox error L2002:fix-up overflow at 5 in segment code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dosbox

I am learning to link modules in 8086 assembly.I have got 2 files.test.asm and utils.asm .First I compile them with `masm utils` and `masm test`,then I try to link test with utils using `link test utils`,however,I get this error
[image]

test.asm code

```
.386
extrn wrhax:near

code segment use16
    mov ax,5
    call wrhax
    mov ah,4CH
    int 21H
code ends
end
```

utils.asm code
(the wrhax function is to display the value in AX)

```
.386
.model small
public wrhax

assume cs:code
stack segment use16 stack
    db 100 dup(0)
stack ends

code segment use16

disp_ch     proc
        push dx
        push ax
        mov  ah,02h
        mov  dl,al
        int  21h
        pop  ax
        pop  dx
        ret
disp_ch     endp

wrhax proc
        push    ax 
        push    dx 
        mov dx,ax 
        mov ch, 4 
L1: 
        mov cl, 4 
        rol dx, cl 
        mov al,dl 
        and al,0FH 
        add al,30h 
        cmp al,3ah 
        jl printit 
        add al,7h 
printit: 
        call  disp_ch 
        dec ch 
        jnz L1
        pop dx 
        pop ax 
        ret 4
wrhax endp
code ends
end
```

Enviroment:dosbox windows 10

Comment: Since you're using MASM 5.x, shouldn't you put the `extern` declaration in the same segment that the same segment that the symbol is defined in (i.e. `code`)?

Comment: From the MASM Progremmer's Guide: _"Although LINK determines the actual address of an external symbol, the assembler assumes a default
segment for the symbol, based on the location of the external directive in the source code. You should
therefore position EXTERN and
EXTERNDEF directives according to these rules:
· If you know which segment defines an external symbol, put the EXTERN statement in that segment."_